# Problemas al seleccionar y generar listas desplegables, python

Tags: python, lista, framework

tengo un problema en mi código, se trata de lo siguiente mi código genera varias listas desplegable según la cantidad que se ingrese previamente en campo de texto, el limite es de 9

```
def itemsCilindros(self, count, pagee):
    pagee = pagee

    global itemsCilindros

    itemsCilindros = []

    count = count + 1

    for formularioIndividual in range(1, count):
        itemsCilindros.append(
            Container(
                height=250,
                width=150,
                bgcolor="white",
                content=Column(
                    spacing=10,
                    controls=[
                        Text(f"Cilindro {str(formularioIndividual)}"),
                        self.empresa,
                        self.tamano,
                        self.pico
                    ]
                )
            )
        )
        pagee.update()
    
    return itemsCilindros
```

el problema esta a la hora de seleccionar las opciones de la lista desplegable, si selecciono una opcion de cualquier lista, en todas se selecciona la misma opción, pero curiosamente solo sucede cuando se llama esta funcion por segunda vez, a lo que me refiero es que cuando inicia mi aplicacion y llamno a esta funcion por primera vez no se seleccionan todos las lista desplegables, si no una por una, alguien me puede ayuda, gracias.

```
    self.empresa = Dropdown(hint_text="Seleccionar empresa", options=[dropdown.Option("Radelco"), dropdown.Option("Paco Gas"), dropdown.Option("Comunal")])
    self.tamano = Dropdown(hint_text="Seleccionar tamaño", options=[dropdown.Option("Pequeña"), dropdown.Option("Mediana"), dropdown.Option("Regular"), dropdown.Option("Grande")])
    self.pico = Dropdown(hint_text="Seleccionar pico", options=[dropdown.Option("Presion"), dropdown.Option("Rosca")])
```

Estas son la variables de las listas

Destaco que mi app la estoy desarrollando en un framework llamado FLET, y es de escritorio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nota: No puedo probar el código, así que me disculpo si algo resulta incorrecto. Sin embargo, espero que sirva.

##### Origen

El problema tiene relación con el funcionamiento de Python. Se puede encontrar en estas líneas dentro del for de itemsCilindros:

```
controls=[
          Text(f"Cilindro {str(formularioIndividual)}"),
          self.empresa,
          self.tamano,
          self.pico
]
```

Donde asumes que el contenido de la lista controls se copia, pero esto no es así. En realidad, el contenido de las listas, variables, atributos, etc, no son más que ids que dirigen hacia el verdadero objeto guardado en memoria.

Esto lo podés comprobar con la función id, que devuelve la id que usa Python,  y el operador is (no confundir con ==) que nos indica si dos variables tienen la misma id, es decir, `a is b` es equivalente a `id(a) == id(b)`.

Te dejo un código para que jueges un poco y compruebes esto:

```
a = {}
same_item_list = [a, a]
```

Aquí, códigos como `a is same_list_item[0]` y `same_list_item[0] is same_list_item[1]` te darán verdadero, y modificar el diccionario a, afectará también a `same_item_list`.

En resumen, estás trabajando con los mismos dropdown en cada item.

##### Solución

Lamentablemente, no hay otra que colocar la creación de los dropdown dentro del bucle for:

```
for formularioIndividual in range(1, count):
    empresa = Dropdown(hint_text="Seleccionar empresa", options=[dropdown.Option("Radelco"), dropdown.Option("Paco Gas"), dropdown.Option("Comunal")])
    tamano = Dropdown(hint_text="Seleccionar tamaño", options=[dropdown.Option("Pequeña"), dropdown.Option("Mediana"), dropdown.Option("Regular"), dropdown.Option("Grande")])
    pico = Dropdown(hint_text="Seleccionar pico", options=[dropdown.Option("Presion"), dropdown.Option("Rosca")])        

    itemsCilindros.append(
        Container(
            height=250,
            width=150,
            bgcolor="white",
            content=Column(
                spacing=10,
                controls=[
                    Text(f"Cilindro {str(formularioIndividual)}"),
                    empresa,
                    tamano,
                    pico
                ]
            )
        )
    )
    pagee.update()
```

##### Consejos adicionales

- `pagee = pagee` es redundante en este caso.
- global casi nunca resulta útil, si estás trabajando con clases, es mejor usar atributos. Esto debido a que si instancias dos veces la misma clase, ambas van a querer usar la misma variable, dando comportamientos extraños. En cambio, las clases tienen su propio "espacio" que no entra en conflicto con otras instancias ni clases.

Comment: Muchas gracias me sirvió ya no se seleccionan todos a la vez